# Refine Search SQL with Custom Pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Working with an asp.net mvc application and c#. We are working on a search page.

**Updated with my Answer. Please see my own answer below and suggest**

unfortunately select into is not working in sql azure http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/04/10007212.aspx

Help me

I have the below tables to to show my item search result

Item Table

- ITEMID,SHOPID, ITEMNAME, DESCRIPTION, PRICE,CATID

Shop Table

- SHOPId, HEADER, CITYID, ACTIVE

City Table

- CITYID, CITYName,REGIONID,CountryISO

Category Table

- CATID, CATNAME

This is my Search Query that gives the paginated result for the given criteria

```
DECLARE @unitItems INT=20
DECLARE @sortOrder INT=0
DECLARE @catId INT
DECLARE @search NVARCHAR (100)=''
DECLARE @REGIONID INT=0
DECLARE @cityId INT=0
DECLARE @maxPrice DECIMAL (10, 2)
DECLARE @page INT
DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME2 (0)
set @unitItems=20
set @catId=0
set @sortOrder=0
set @search=''
set @cityId=1
set @maxPrice=0
set @page=1
set @currentDate='2013-02-24 13:14:58.073'

;WITH itemresult AS (
  SELECT IT.ITEMID, IT.ITEMNAME, IT.DESCRIPTION, IT.PRICE,
  IT.CATID, C.CATNAME AS CATNAME,S.HEADER AS SHOPHEADER,CI.CITYNAME AS CITY, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IT.SHOWDATE DESC) AS RowNumber
  FROM ITEM AS IT INNER JOIN SHOP AS S ON IT.SHOPId = S.ShopId 
  INNER JOIN CITY AS CI ON CI.CITYID = S.CITYID
  INNER JOIN COUNTRY AS CY ON CI.COUNTRYISO = CY.COUNTRYISO 
  INNER JOIN REGION AS R ON CI.REGIONID = R.REGIONID 
  INNER JOIN CITY AS CI2 ON CI2.CITYID = @cityId 
  INNER JOIN CATEGORY AS C ON IT.CATID = C.CATID    

  WHERE S.ACTIVE = 1   

  GROUP BY IT.ITEMID, IT.ITEMNAME, IT.HEADER, IT.DESCRIPTION, IT.PRICE, 
  IT.CATID, IT.SHOWDATE,S.HEADER,C.CATNAME,CI.CITYNAME) 

  SELECT IT.*, CEILING(CAST(RN AS float) / @unitItems) AS UNITPAGES, RN AS UNITROWS 
  FROM itemresult IT 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(RowNumber) AS RN FROM itemresult) SUBQ ON 1=1 
  WHERE IT.RowNumber BETWEEN (@page - 1) * @unitItems + 1 
  AND @unitItems * @page
```

**Problem:**

Now the problem is we are adding new changes in the UI. Search UI now will show something like below

**First Result Set** ***-->Assume 230 records found overall***

Search Result as you see in Fiddle

**Second Result Set** ***-->Different Categories & Count from 230 records***

> CatId, CatName, TotalCountInSearch

Ex: 1 Books 25 & 2 Sports 43 & 8 Others 52.
  Show I can show like below in UI

- All Categories (120)
- Books (25)
- Sports (43)
- Others (52)

And **Third Result Set** ***-->Different Cities& Count from 230 records***

> CityId, CityName, TotalCountInSearch

for displaying below in UI

- All Cities(10)
- Chennai (4)
- Banglore (3)
- Others (3)

> **How can i retrieve these counts and names like all categories,books,
>   allcities, etc? Any help or suggesstions are welcome**.

**[Click and View SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52bbb/1)**

I would like to get these counts based on the search criteria. wish to retreive this as another result set from my procedure

**MAIN UPDATE:**

> I have all the schema and actual dynamic query uploaded here 
>   https://github.com/Padayappa/SQLProblem/blob/master/PaginationIssue

Comment: Question is not very clear. It would be easy to understand your requirement if you could show expected results for the given fiddle?

Comment: Looking similar to this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52bbb/61

Comment: Sorry, since you already having required results, what is wrong with those queries? Do you mean that you need to get those 3 result sets in a one go?

Comment: @Kaf, I want all 3 result sets in same procedure. I mean exec a search  procedure should return search result, city count, category count information. I am not that expert in SQL. This query was written by one of colleague and he left. I have no idea, how efficiently with out affecting performance to get city, category info

Comment: I have answered the question and also have added some extra details which I thought would be useful for you. Ex; how to execute new procedure called `myStoredProcedure` from `SSMS`/`C#`

Answer (score 4):

Try this. I hope this will satisfy your expection

```
CREATE VIEW vSequence AS
WITH itemresult AS (
  SELECT IT.ITEMID, IT.ITEMNAME, IT.DESCRIPTION, IT.PRICE,
  IT.CATID, C.CATNAME AS CATNAME,S.HEADER AS SHOPHEADER,CI.CITYNAME AS CITY,CI.CITYID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IT.SHOWDATE DESC) AS RowNumber
  FROM ITEM AS IT INNER JOIN SHOP AS S ON IT.SHOPId = S.ShopId
  INNER JOIN CITY AS CI ON CI.CITYID = S.CITYID
  INNER JOIN COUNTRY AS CY ON CI.COUNTRYISO = CY.COUNTRYISO
  INNER JOIN REGION AS R ON CI.REGIONID = R.REGIONID
  INNER JOIN CITY AS CI2 ON CI2.CITYID = 1
  INNER JOIN CATEGORY AS C ON IT.CATID = C.CATID

  WHERE S.ACTIVE = 1

  GROUP BY IT.ITEMID, IT.ITEMNAME, IT.HEADER, IT.DESCRIPTION, IT.PRICE,
  IT.CATID, IT.SHOWDATE,S.HEADER,C.CATNAME,CI.CITYNAME,CI.CITYID)

SELECT * FROM itemresult IT

GO

  SELECT IT.*, CEILING(CAST(RN AS float) / 20) AS UNITPAGES, RN AS UNITROWS
  FROM vSequence IT
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(RowNumber) AS RN FROM vSequence) SUBQ ON 1=1
  WHERE IT.RowNumber BETWEEN (1 - 1) * 20 + 1
  AND 20 * 1
GO
SELECT  IT.CATID,RS.CATNAME , CONVERT(varchar(10), SUM(CASE WHEN IT.CATID = CAT.CATID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Count'
FROM vSequence RS INNER JOIN ITEM IT ON RS.CATID = IT.CATID
INNER JOIN CATEGORY CAT
ON IT.CATID = CAT.CATID GROUP BY IT.CATID,RS.CATNAME
GO
SELECT  CIT.CITYID,CITYNAME,CONVERT(varchar(10), SUM(CASE WHEN CIT.REGIONID =  REG.REGIONID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Count'
FROM COUNTRY CON INNER JOIN REGION REG
ON CON.COUNTRYISO = REG.COUNTRYISO
INNER JOIN CITY CIT ON CIT.REGIONID =  REG.REGIONID
INNER JOIN  vSequence RS ON CIT.CITYID=RS.CITYID GROUP BY REG.REGIONID,CITYNAME, CIT.CITYID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52bbb/61) sample.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand from your comments, I think you *need* is to get *`3 result sets by executing a single stored procedure`*. Also you want to know if the queries are optimised.

I think your *vSequence* `VIEW` is fine as it is (So, I am not adding here to my answer). What you need is to *`create a stored procedure`* to get three different result sets `using your view` as below. I have taken the variable list you have declared in the fiddle as parameters to the stored procedure. I have commented next to each variable. Since your filtering requirements are not clear I leave them as there are.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProcedure 
   @unitItems INT=20, --number of items per page
   @sortOrder INT=0, --not used
   @catId INT, --not in use 
   @search NVARCHAR (100)='', --not used
   @REGIONID INT=0, -- not used
   @cityId INT=0, -- not used
   @maxPrice DECIMAL (10, 2), -- not used
   @page INT, --page number
   @currentDate DATETIME2 (0) -- not used
AS 
BEGIN

    /*
      Query 1
      Note: I have assumed your @page start at 1 and also changed the where clause 
      to bring correct data based on @page & @unitItems parameters 
    */
    SELECT IT.*, CEILING(CAST(RN AS float) / 20) AS UNITPAGES, RN AS UNITROWS
    FROM vSequence IT INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(RowNumber) AS RN FROM vSequence) SUBQ ON 1=1
    WHERE IT.RowNumber BETWEEN (@unitItems * (@page - 1) + 1) AND @unitItems 

    /* Query 2 */
    SELECT  IT.CATID,RS.CATNAME , CONVERT(varchar(10), 
            SUM(CASE WHEN IT.CATID = CAT.CATID THEN    1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Count'
    FROM vSequence RS 
              INNER JOIN ITEM IT ON RS.CATID = IT.CATID 
              INNER JOIN CATEGORY CAT ON IT.CATID = CAT.CATID 
    GROUP BY IT.CATID,RS.CATNAME

    /* Query 3 */
    SELECT  CIT.CITYID,CITYNAME,CONVERT(varchar(10), 
            SUM(CASE WHEN CIT.REGIONID =   REG.REGIONID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Count'
    FROM COUNTRY CON 
             INNER JOIN REGION REG ON CON.COUNTRYISO = REG.COUNTRYISO
             INNER JOIN CITY CIT ON CIT.REGIONID =  REG.REGIONID
             INNER JOIN  vSequence RS ON CIT.CITYID=RS.CITYID 
    GROUP BY REG.REGIONID,CITYNAME, CIT.CITYID
 END
```

Below is how to execute the stored procedure in `Management Studio` (Please use appropriate values for parameters):

```
DECLARE @unitItems INT = 20, 
        @sortOrder INT = 0, 
        @catId INT = 0,
        @search NVARCHAR (100) = '', 
        @REGIONID INT = 0, 
        @cityId INT = 1,
        @maxPrice DECIMAL (10, 2) = 0,
        @page INT = 1,
        @currentDate DATETIME2 (0) = '2013-02-24 13:14:58.073'

EXEC myStoredProcedure 
       @unitItems,
       @sortOrder,
       @catId,
       @search,
       @REGIONID,
       @cityId,
       @maxPrice,
       @page,
       @currentDate
```

To execute this stored procedure within your `C#` code use a parameterised query with a `DataAdapter` as below:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection connection =  new SqlConnection("your-Connection-String-here"))
{

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("myStoredProcedure", connection);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitItems",20);
    //add other parameters as above here
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page",1); //correct page number
    adapter.Fill(ds);
}

//Now you can access all query results as 
ds.Tables[0]; //results from query1
ds.Tables[1]; //results from query2
ds.Tables[2]; //results from query3
```

Comment: Updated with GITHub url. You can see my actual dynamic query and help me

Comment: I tried to resolve. Here is my implementation. Let me know is this ok? https://github.com/Padayappa/SQLProblem/blob/master/PaginationResolved

Comment: unfortunately select into is not working in sql azure http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/04/10007212.aspx

Comment: I am not using `select into`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i created the below SP and resolved the problem.

**Please let me know is this is correct approach?**

> **I used temp table, Grouping SETS, Grouping_ID**

You can see the code here https://github.com/Padayappa/SQLProblem/blob/master/PaginationResolved

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Item_SearchItems_New]
 (
   @ShopNr INT
,@unitItems INT = 20
,@sortOrder INT = 0
,@language CHAR(2) = 'EN'
,@catId INT
,@search NVARCHAR(100) = ''
,@countryIso NCHAR(2) = ''
,@regionNr INT = 0
,@cityId INT = 0
,@maxPrice DECIMAL(10, 2)
,@page INT
,@currentDate DATETIME2(0)
,@distance NUMERIC(4, 1)
,@isFavoriteShop BIT = 0
,@currentUserNr INT = 0
,@latitude FLOAT(53) = 0
,@longitude FLOAT(53) = 0
,@itemType TINYINT = 0
,@unitRows INT OUTPUT
,@unitPages INT OUTPUT
 )
 AS
 BEGIN
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@sqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@sqlTempTable NVARCHAR(MAX) = '#itemSearch'
        ,@sqlCountTempTable NVARCHAR(MAX) = '#itemCount'
        ,@sqlInto NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@sqlFrom NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@sqlClause NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@sqlGroup NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@params NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@citySearch bit = 0
        ,@gpsSearch bit = 0
        ,@sortOrderString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ORDER BY IT.CREATEDATE DESC'
        ,@sortOrderString2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

IF (@cityid <= 0) AND (@currentUserNr > 0) AND (@latitude = 0)
    SELECT  @cityid = CITYID
    FROM    USERINFO
    WHERE   USERNR = @currentUserNr
ELSE IF (@cityid <= 0) AND (@latitude > 0)
    SET @gpsSearch = 1
ELSE IF (@cityid > 0)
    SET @citySearch = 1



IF (@sortOrderString2 = '')
    SET @sortOrderString2 = @sortOrderString

IF (@unitItems = 0)
    SET @unitItems = 20

IF (@page <= 0)
    SET @page = 1

SET @sqlSelect =
    'SELECT     J.URLNAME
                ,IT.ITEMNR
                ,IT.USERNR
                ,IT.ShopNR
                ,IT.ITEMID
                ,IT.ITEMNAME
                ,IT.HEADER
                ,IT.DESCRIPTION
                ,IT.PRICE
                ,IT.CREATEDATE
                ,IT.ITEMSTATUS
                ,IT.CURRENCYCODE
                ,IT.CATID
                ,IT.VISIT
                ,IT.ENDDATE
                ,IT.PREAMBLE
                ,IT.SHOWDATE
                ,IT.LASTUPDATED
                ,C.CATNAME AS CATNAME

                ,J.HEADER AS ShopHEADER
                ,J.LATITUDE
                ,J.LONGITUDE
                ,R.REGIONNAME AS REGIONNAME
                ,CY.COUNTRYISO
                ,R.REGIONNR
                ,CY.COUNTRYNAME AS COUNTRYNAME
                ,CI.CITYNAME AS CITY
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (' + @sortOrderString + ') AS RowNumber'

SET @sqlGroup =
    ' GROUP BY  J.URLNAME
                ,IT.ITEMNR
                ,IT.USERNR
                ,IT.ShopNR
                ,IT.ITEMID
                ,IT.ITEMNAME
                ,IT.HEADER
                ,IT.DESCRIPTION
                ,IT.PRICE
                ,IT.CREATEDATE
                ,IT.ITEMSTATUS
                ,IT.CURRENCYCODE
                ,IT.CATID
                ,IT.VISIT
                ,IT.ENDDATE
                ,IT.PREAMBLE
                ,IT.SHOWDATE
                ,IT.LASTUPDATED
                ,C.CATNAME

                ,J.HEADER
                ,J.LATITUDE
                ,J.LONGITUDE
                ,R.REGIONNAME
                ,CY.COUNTRYISO
                ,R.REGIONNR
                ,CY.COUNTRYNAME
                ,CI.CITYNAME'

SET @sqlFrom =
    ' FROM      dbo.ITEM AS IT
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Shop AS J
            ON  IT.ShopNR = J.ShopNR
    INNER JOIN  dbo.CITY AS CI
            ON  CI.CITYID = J.CITYID
    INNER JOIN  dbo.COUNTRY AS CY
            ON  CI.COUNTRYISO = CY.COUNTRYISO
    INNER JOIN  dbo.REGION AS R
            ON  CI.REGIONNR = R.REGIONNR'

    SET @sqlFrom = @sqlFrom +
        ' INNER JOIN    dbo.CATEGORY AS C
                ON  IT.CATID = C.CATID '

    SET @sqlClause =
        ' WHERE     J.ACTIVE = 1
                AND IT.ITEMSTATUS = 1
                AND IT.ENDDATE > @currentDate'      

    IF (@itemType = 1) 
        SET @sqlClause = @sqlClause +
            ' AND IT.ITEMTYPE = 1'

    IF (@catId > 0)
        SET @sqlClause = @sqlClause +
            ' AND (C.CATID = @catId OR C.PARENTCATID = @catId)'

    IF (@ShopNr > 0)
        SET @sqlClause = @sqlClause +
            ' AND IT.ShopNR = @ShopNr'

    IF (@search <> '') 
        SET @sqlClause = @sqlClause +
            ' AND ((IT.HEADER LIKE ''%' + @search + '%'') OR (IT.DESCRIPTION LIKE ''%' + @search + '%''))'

    SET @sqlInto = ' INTO ' + @sqlTempTable + ' ';

    SET @sql =  @sqlSelect +
                @sqlInto +
                @sqlFrom +
                @sqlClause +
                @sqlGroup

    SET @sql = @sql + ';

        SELECT  @unitRows = @@ROWCOUNT
                ,@unitPages = (@unitRows / @unitItems) + 1;

        SELECT  *
        FROM    ' + @sqlTempTable + ' AS IT
        WHERE   RowNumber BETWEEN (@page - 1) * @unitItems + 1 AND @unitItems * @page
        ' + @sortOrderString2 + ';

        SELECT      CATNAME
                    ,CITY
                    ,COUNT(*) AS ITEMCOUNT
                    ,GROUPING_ID(CATNAME, CITY) AS ITEMCOUNTTYPEID
        INTO        '+ @sqlCountTempTable + '
        FROM        ' + @sqlTempTable + '
        GROUP BY    GROUPING SETS
                    (
                        (CATNAME)
                        ,(CITY)
                        ,()
                    )

        SELECT      ISNULL(CATNAME, ''All Categories'') AS CATNAME
                    ,ITEMCOUNT
        FROM        '+ @sqlCountTempTable + '
        WHERE       ITEMCOUNTTYPEID IN (1, 3)
        ORDER BY    ITEMCOUNTTYPEID DESC
                    ,CATNAME

        SELECT      ISNULL(CITY, ''All Cities'') AS CITY
                    ,ITEMCOUNT
        FROM        '+ @sqlCountTempTable + '
        WHERE       ITEMCOUNTTYPEID IN (2, 3)
        ORDER BY    ITEMCOUNTTYPEID DESC
                    ,CITY';

    SELECT @params =
        N'@language nchar(2), ' +
        N'@ShopNr int, ' +
        N'@cityId int, ' +
        N'@catId int, ' +
        N'@distance numeric(4,1), ' +
        N'@currentDate datetime, ' + 
        N'@unitItems int,' + 
        N'@countryIso nchar(2),' + 
        N'@regionNr int,' + 
        N'@page int,' + 
        N'@currentUserNr int,' +
        N'@latitude float,' +
        N'@longitude float,' +
        N'@unitRows int OUTPUT,' +
        N'@unitPages int OUTPUT'

--print @sql

EXEC    sp_executesql @sql
        ,@params
        ,@language
        ,@ShopNr
        ,@cityId
        ,@catId
        ,@distance
        ,@currentDate
        ,@unitItems
        ,@countryIso
        ,@regionNr
        ,@page
        ,@currentUserNr
        ,@latitude
        ,@longitude
        ,@unitRows OUTPUT
        ,@unitPages OUTPUT
END
GO


DECLARE @unitPages INT
    ,@unitRows INT

exec Item_SearchItems_New @ShopNr=0,@unitItems=20,@catId=0,@language='',@sortOrder=0,@search=default,@countryIso='in',
@regionNr=2702259,@cityId=2702261,@maxPrice=0,@page=1,@distance=50,@currentDate='2013-02-24 19:29:50.623',@isFavoriteShop=0,
@currentUserNr=0,@latitude=0,@longitude=0,@itemType=0,@unitRows = @unitRows OUTPUT, @unitPages = @unitPages OUTPUT

SELECT  @unitPages, @unitRows
```

Answer (score 0):

this is to retrieve count base on categories

```
select 'All categories' catname, count(*) catcount from itemtable
union all
select catname, count(catid) catcount
from itemtable inner join categorytable on categorytable.catid = itemtable.catid
group by catname
```

this is to retrieve count based on city

```
select 'All cities' cityname, count(*) catcount from itemtable
union all
select cityname, count(catid) catcount 
from itemtable inner join shoptable on itemtable.shopid = shoptable.shopid
inner join citytable on citytable.cityid = shoptable.cityid
group by cityname
```

Comment: I have updated with Fiddle. I want the same SQL query to return. Please check the fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52bbb/1  I Need another result set that gives me these counts based on search scenario

Comment: Your query gives all Categories and Cities for the whole. I need it from the filtered records matches my search parameters

Comment: Updated my question with more information for bounty of 50 points